# Why double a=(double)('z'/'A') gives only integer part in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm still a beginner in C++ so I seek some help with the basics.
Here, in the following code, I'm using type-casting to find value of 122/65 but I'm getting only the integer part even with double data type.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()

{

    double a=(double)('z'/'A');

    cout<<a;

    return 0;

}
```

Can someone provide me a good reason for this??

Thank you.

Comment: Because `'z'` and `'A'` are both *integers*, and you have an integer division. You only cast the *result* of the integer division to a `double`.

Comment: And can you please explain to us why you use *characters* in your division? What is the *actual* problem you attempt to solve by that very odd-looking division?

Comment: `((double)'z')/'A'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You make an integer division and then you typecast the result to double. Basically you have:

```
(double) (122/65) = (double) (1) = 1.0
                              ^ truncated -> integer division
```

If you want a floating point division you can do it this way:

```
double a = (double)'z' / (double)'A';
//     a = 122.0       / 65.0
```

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, edited. Thanks.